# Getting "Not all variablesbound error"

Tags: .net

I am getting error while executing cmd.executenonquery()
what i am doing wrong here

```
            OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

            cmd.BindByName = true;
            try
            {

                if (unsetDefaultViewId != 0)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE WI_VIEWUSER SET DEFAULT_FLAG = "
                                    + " CASE "
                                    + "    WHEN SEC_USR_ID = :p_userid AND VIEW_ID = :p_unsetDefviewId THEN 'N' "
                                    + "    WHEN SEC_USR_ID = :p_userid AND VIEW_ID = :p_setDefViewId  THEN 'Y' "
                                    + "    ELSE DEFAULT_FLAG "
                                    + " END ";

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_setDefViewId",OracleDbType.Int32)).Value =  unsetDefaultViewId;

                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE WI_VIEWUSER SET DEFAULT_FLAG  = 'Y' WHERE VIEW_ID = :p_setDefViewId and  SEC_USR_ID = :p_userid";
                }

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_userid", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value = userid;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_setDefViewId",OracleDbType.Int32)).Value =  setDefaultViewId;

//getting error here
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE WI_VIEW SET CREATED_DATE = sysdate WHERE VIEW_ID = :p_setDefViewId" ;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                transaction.Commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copy-pasted a wrong name here:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_setDefViewId",OracleDbType.Int32)).Value =  unsetDefaultViewId;
```

should be

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_unsetDefviewId",OracleDbType.Int32)).Value =  unsetDefaultViewId;
//                                        ^^^^^
```

Currently, when `unsetDefaultViewId != 0` your code sets `"p_setDefViewId"` parameter twice, while `"p_unsetDefViewId"` remains unset.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out my mistake one more thing for the second update statement do i need to add parameter again before running the second executenonquery as i am getting error illegal variable name/number

Comment: @Yogesh No, since `:unsetDefviewId` is not mentioned in the statement, you do not need to `Add()` the parameter for it in the `else` branch. Both statements share `:p_userid` and `:p_setDefViewId`, so your setting them after the `else` is also correct.

Comment: sorry its the third update stetment which is causing problem since i already have setdefviewid parameter in cmd cant i reuse it in the third update statement but its giving me error

Comment: @Yogesh I'm nearly certain that once you do a `CommandText = ...`, you need to `Add(...)` all the parameters again.

Comment: i tried doin this i tried adding setDefViewId parameter after the third update statement but i still get the same error

Comment: thanks a lot i solved my problem i had to clear my parameters first and then add parameter again